# Set Site logo in SharePoint Online using PowerShell Script and CSOM

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

Has anyone been able to set the Site Logo on a SharePoint Online site using Powershell and CSOM ?
Thanks

Nigel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solves setting Site Logo (ctx is ClientContext):

ctx.Web.SiteLogoUrl = "/teams/test/SiteAssets/45.jpg";

ctx.Web.Update();

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Answer (score 1):

According to UserVoice request [Make the SiteLogoUrl property available in CSOM](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/6234945-make-the-sitelogourl-property-available-in-csom) and post [UserVoice driving improvements to SharePoint API](http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/uservoice-driving-improvements-sharepoint-api/) the **new** version of [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) `Web` class supports `SiteLogoUrl` property.

How to set `Web.SiteLogoUrl property` using CSOM in PowerShell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
   $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
}

Function Web-SetLogo([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Content,[string]$SiteLogoUrl)
{
   $Context.Web.SiteLogoUrl = $SiteLogoUrl
   $Context.Web.Update()
   $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}

$UserName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password

Web-SetLogo -Content $context -SiteLogoUrl "/SiteAssets/ContosoLogo.jpg"

$context.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the script to change default sharepoint logo using powershell in sharepoint 2016

```
$logoLocation= "http://sharepoint2016/SiteAssets/MyCompanyLogo.png"
$oSite=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sharepoint2016/")
foreach($oWeb in $oSite.Allwebs) {
$oWeb.SiteLogoUrl=$logoLocation
$oWeb.Update()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Script lets you change the logo of a complete site collection with one click:**

**Source: https://github.com/t1llo/change_logo_SharePointOnline-PS**

**Important:** only works when executed in sharePoint Online Management Shell.

```
#Add PowerShell Module for SharePoint Online
    Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell -DisableNameChecking

    ##Configuration variables
    $SiteUrl = "https://yoursite.collection.com/"
    $LogoURL="https://yourlogo.com"

    Try {
        #Get Credentials to connect
        $Cred = Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

        #Get the Root web
        $Web = $Ctx.Web
        $Ctx.Load($Web)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Function to change Logo for the given web
        Function Update-Logo($Web)
        {
            #Update Logo
            $Web.SiteLogoUrl = $LogoURL
            $Web.Update()
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-host "Updated Logo for Web:" $Web.URL

            #Process each subsite in the site
            $Subsites = $Web.Webs
            $Ctx.Load($Subsites)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()        
            Foreach ($SubSite in $Subsites)
            {
                #Call the function Recursively
                Update-Logo($Subsite)
            }
        }

        #Call the function to change logo of the web
        Update-Logo($Web)
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error updating Logo!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
```